# Exception has occurred. Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, vscode

Estoy teniendo problemas al usar el compilador dentro de VSCode.
Me sale el error
***Exception has occurred. Segmentation fault***

Probé desinstalando VSCode, MingW, editando el PATH, nada funciona.

Ví que el error es de memoria o privilegios de acceso pero en mi caso, me pasa con cualquier código.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{  
    int edad;
    char sexo;
    float altura;
        cout << "Ingrese edad: ";
        cin >> edad;
        cout << "\nIngrese sexo (f/m): ";
        cin >> sexo;
        cout << "\nIngrese su altura en mts: ";
        cin >> altura;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

En éste ejemplo me sale en la linea 15 ***cin >> edad;***

Comment: Estás en Stackoverflow en español. Por favor escribe en la pregunta en español.

Comment: uy, gracias, no me di cuenta

Comment: El código está bien. Lo acabo de probar y no obtengo ningún error. No sé que lo puede estar causando. Si lo debugearas podrías obtener alguna pista más. Tampoco podemos ayudarte mucho si no  el problema no es reproducible. Te puedo sugerir que cambies de compilador.

Comment: con DevC funciona perfecto.

Comment: No creo que sea el problema, pero quita la cabecera `stdlib.h`. Esa es para C, mientras que `cstdlib` es la de C++, que además ya la tienes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione eliminando todas las variables PATH y reinstalando desde 0 VSCode. Es un error de instalación de VSCode y MingW